# Testing: Ensure a method is called in AWS NodeJS Lamda function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a NodeJS lambda function that I run on AWS. I want to write a simple test for the `.handler` function.

**CODE**

Here is the `index.js` code:

```
// importing dependencies
var mySQLWriter = require('./mySQLWriterService');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  console.log('Printing out JSON.stringify(event): ');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
  event.Records.forEach((record) => {
    if (record.eventName === 'INSERT') {
      console.log('We have an INSERT happening.');
      mySQLWriter(record, callback);
    }
  });
};
```

I want to write a simple test that would pass if `mySQLWriter` is called.

Using Mocha and Chai and with help from dashmud below, I have attempted to do this, but it isn't working, here is my `indexTests.js` code:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const spies = require('chai-spies');
chai.use(spies);
const appStart = require('../index');
const mySQLWriter = require('../mySQLWriterService');

describe('lambda function', () => {
  it('should call the mySQLWriter() function', () => {
      const spy = chai.spy.on(mySQLWriter, 'mySQLWriter');
      let event = {
        Records: [
          {
            eventName: 'INSERT',
            dynamodb: {
              NewImage: {
                DeviceId: { S: 'Device 000' },
                TimeStamp: { S: '2018-03-20T11:15:31.668Z' },
                Accuracy: { S: '5' },
                Latitude: { S: '53.639645' },
                Longitude: { S: '-1.782491' },
                Speed: { S: '1' },
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      };
      const context = {};

      appStart.handler(event, context, () => {
        expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
        done();
      })
  });
});
```

When I run the test, I get:

[image]

Comment: Where is your done() coming from?  Anyway, as others have pointed out that since the mysqlservice is not posted, it is a little difficult. What I have done is simply use your posted code and made it work. Please check out my answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Removed **chai** and used **sinon** instead

```
//const chai = require('chai');
//const expect = chai.expect;
const sinon = require('sinon');
//chai.use(sinon);
const SQLWriter = require('./mysqlwriterservice.js');
const appStart = require('./sinonsqlwriter');

describe('lambda function', () => {
  it('should call the mySQLWriter() function', () => {
      const spy = sinon.spy(SQLWriter, 'mySQLWriter');
      let event = {
        Records: [
          {
            eventName: 'INSERT',
            dynamodb: {
              NewImage: {
                DeviceId: { S: 'Device 000' },
                TimeStamp: { S: '2018-03-20T11:15:31.668Z' },
                Accuracy: { S: '5' },
                Latitude: { S: '53.639645' },
                Longitude: { S: '-1.782491' },
                Speed: { S: '1' },
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      };
      const context = {};

      appStart.handler(event, context, () => {
        console.log("Call count"+spy.callCount)
        //expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
      })
  });
});
```

// sinonsqlwriter.js

// importing dependencies

```
const SQLWriter = require('./mysqlwriterservice.js');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  console.log('Printing out JSON.stringify(event): ');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
  event.Records.forEach((record) => {
    if (record.eventName === 'INSERT') {
      console.log('We have an INSERT happening.');
      SQLWriter.mySQLWriter(record, callback);
      SQLWriter.mySQLWriter(record, callback);
    }
  });
  callback();
};
```

// mysqlwriterservice.js
I used the code from your shared link. Below is the **updated** answer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I used your code, but it still doesn't pass for me. Here's the code in the mySQLWriterService https://pastebin.com/raw/B0ABZJ3X

Comment: I don't use mysql nor have access to a lambda function on AWS but your code works alright for my test. Please check out the updated part in my answer. I used your mySQLWriterService code as is. Added a blank app-configuration module. In your response, let me know what is the error that you get. Is it the test failing or the callback not obtaining the right response? Please share the screenshot in your response.

Comment: @Ciwan - as an after thought, you may have a larger problem here because of testability. The handler method's contract is not sufficiently abstracted and so is not as testable as a ES6 class may have been because another common test would be to check if the call to the SQLWriter method has been made with the right arguments and 'record' is a local *=(loop level)* variable that the caller cannot test because it is passing the 'event', the whole JSON object, as the argument!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not calling the handler function, so try changing

```
appStart()
```

to

```
appStart.handler(someEvent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `appStart` is just a module. You need to call the `handler` inside your `appStart` (`index.js`) and do your assertions inside the callback.

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const spies = require('chai-spies');
chai.use(spies);
const appStart = require('../index');

describe('lambda function', () => {
  it('should call the mySQLWriter() function', done => {
      const spy = chai.spy.on(mySQLWriter, 'mySQLWriter');
      const event = {};
      const context = {};
      appStart.handler(event, context, () => {
        expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
        done();
      })
  });
});
```

---

Update based on comment and updated question:

Based on your screenshot, it seems like `mySQLWriterService.js` exports an object with a `mySQLWriter` function.

This will not work.

```
var mySQLWriter = require('./mySQLWriterService');
```

I think is should be like this:

```
const mySQLWriter = require('./mySQLWriterService').mysqlWriter;
```

(I'm not 100% sure as you did not include the code inside your `mySQLWriterService.js`.)

P.S. Don't use `var`. Ever.

Comment: Thank you @dashmug. With your code above, I'm getting close, but it still doesn't work, I'm not sure why. See updated question.

Comment: Here is [the code](https://pastebin.com/raw/B0ABZJ3X). Thanks, I won't use `var` again. But sadly it still doesn't work, even after I added `.mySQLWriter` to the end of the require in `indexTests.js`